# How to show a counter in android UI

Tags: android, multithreading

Can I use a thread for increment a counter and shows it in a frame of Android activity.

```
Public class MainActivity extendsActivity {
        TextView counter;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_counter);
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                                try {
                                    counter.setText("" + i);
                                    System.out.println("Value of i= " + i);
                                    sleep(100);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    }
```

I wrote this code, but it run properly in console, but the text view displays `i=4` in the terminal, I modified the time to sleep(3000) and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't ever want to put sleep in UI Thread that can lead to unresponsive user interface and that is never good. You should use it just to update your graphics. Try replacing your code with this

```
  Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {             
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                   
                try {
                    final int a = i;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {                        
                            counter.setText("" + a);                            
                        }                       
                    });
                    System.out.println("Value of i= " + i);
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

You are going to notice that sleep and for loop is outside UIThread and in your first thread, so basically all of your math is done outside and you just display the results.

This is just a correction of your code and suggestion for further thinking

EDIT: And for you to better understand why your code is not working, you set some value on your TextView, and immediately after you set UIThread to sleep, UIThread blocks instead of giving it time to finish updating graphics, after he finish sleep you set new value, and he never got to update previous one so in the end you see just the last one.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `CountDownTimer`, and update your UI in the `onTick()` method ( this method is executed on the UI Thread):

```
int i=0;
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // this method will be executed every second ( 1000 ms : the second parameter in the CountDownTimer constructor)
                i++;
                txt.setText(i);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        timer.start();
```